# Method that always runs? (Xcode/iOS/Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering how to design a method that always runs in an iOS application. What I'm trying to accomplish is having a point system where each second a point is added to the score throughout the entire time the game is playing.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you can take advantage of SpriteKit.

All things are SKNode in it, and since it's a game API, it will optimize your visual effects. In SpriteKit there is an method called `update`, which is constantly being called, you will only need to set a timer or something to update it once per second.

Take a look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners) or [this](https://www.codefellows.org/blogs/simple-sprite-kit-game-tutorial-part1). These are just some of good tutorials about this matter.